# In iOS: Unable to touch inside the subview in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableview` with Image button. When on touch the button it will add the subview(Table view) dynamically like drop-down shown image below.I can't select the second option in the drop down (table view).

The problem is dropdown height is exceed the table row.so that I can't select the second option.

Anyone has a solution for this? Or any idea to show drop down in `UITableView`?

[image: table view with dropdown].

Edited:

This Working fine in `UITextField` dropdown.but not working in UITableView.

DropDown Code:

```
- (id)showDropDown:(UIButton *)b:(CGFloat *)height:(NSArray *)arr:(NSString *)direction {
    btnSender = b;
    animationDirection = direction;
    self.table = (UIButton *)[super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        CGRect btn = b.frame;
        self.list = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arr];
        if ([direction isEqualToString:@"up"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y, btn.size.width, 0);
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, -5);
        }else if ([direction isEqualToString:@"down"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y+btn.size.height, btn.size.width, 0);
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, 5);
        }

        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

        table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, btn.size.width+btn.size.width, 0)];
        table.delegate = self;
        table.dataSource = self;
        table.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        table.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        table.separatorColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        table.separatorInset=UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        table.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        if ([direction isEqualToString:@"up"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y-*height, btn.size.width, *height);
        } else if([direction isEqualToString:@"down"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y+btn.size.height, btn.size.width, *height);
        }
        table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, btn.size.width, *height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [b.superview addSubview:self];
        [self addSubview:table];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)hideDropDown:(UIButton *)b {
    CGRect btn = b.frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    if ([animationDirection isEqualToString:@"up"]) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y, btn.size.width+btn.size.width, 0);
    }else if ([animationDirection isEqualToString:@"down"]) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y+btn.size.height, btn.size.width+btn.size.width, 0);
    }
    table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, btn.size.width, 0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellText = @"Go get some text for your cell.";
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

    return labelSize.height + 20;
    //return 40;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.list count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text =[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIView * v = [[UIView alloc] init];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self hideDropDown:btnSender];

    UITableViewCell *c = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    [self myDelegate:indexPath.row];
}

- (void) myDelegate:(NSInteger) index{
    [self.delegate niDropDownDelegateMethod:self selectedIndex:index];
}
```

Button `TableView`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"quotelist";

    QuoteListCell *cell = (QuoteListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"QuoteListCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.quoteButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.quoteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dropDownButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;


}

-(void)dropDownButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"searchData row at index:%d",sender.tag);
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;

    if(dropDown == nil) {
        //[self.quoteListTableView setAllowsSelection:NO];

        CGFloat f = 200;
        dropDown = [[MyDropDown alloc]showDropDown:btn :&f :[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Dublicate",@"Create Order", nil] :@"down"];
        dropDown.delegate = self;
    }
    else {
        //[self.quoteListTableView setAllowsSelection:YES];
        [dropDown hideDropDown:btn];
        dropDown=nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code of adding dropdown

Comment: Dropdown code is shared.

Comment: For some time increase the button width. And where you have added the button.And share the code of cellforrowatindex code also.

Comment: what is `self` in this case? Is it a `UIVIew` subclass?

Comment: Share the code where you added image button.@Chidhambaram

Comment: image button code added.

Comment: after your issue solved,pls acknowledge.

Comment: NO,still not working. still i can select first option only.

Comment: The problem is dropdown height is exceed the table row.so that i can't select the second option.How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)showDropDown:(UIButton *)b:(CGFloat *)height:(NSArray *)arr:(NSString *)direction {
    btnSender = b;
    animationDirection = direction;
    self.table = (UIButton *)[super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        CGRect btn = b.frame;
        self.list = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arr];
        if ([direction isEqualToString:@"up"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y, btn.size.width, 0);
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, -5);
        }else if ([direction isEqualToString:@"down"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y+btn.size.height, btn.size.width, 0);
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, 5);
        }

        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

        table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, btn.size.width+btn.size.width, 0)];
        table.delegate = self;
        table.dataSource = self;
        table.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        table.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        table.separatorColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        table.separatorInset=UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        table.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        if ([direction isEqualToString:@"up"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y-*height, btn.size.width, *height);
        } else if([direction isEqualToString:@"down"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y+btn.size.height, btn.size.width, *height);
        }
        table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, btn.size.width, *height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [b.superview.superview addSubview:self];
        [self addSubview:table];
    }
    return self;
}

I have changed one line in the above code, use this.
```

Comment: which line you changed?

Comment: [b.superview.superview addSubview:self];

Comment: No,The problem is dropdown height is exceed the table row.so that i can't select the second option.You have a any idea?

Comment: When adding dropdown to any view, the view height should be greater than the dropdown height. So, add the drop down to the table view.